# How to get failed request Data in Alamofire retry method

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I managed to get the retry to work with Alamofire, however, I would like to get response data object from the previous request so in the should function so that I can make decisions before retry.

I am not sure if that is possible in Alamofire, this is my code :

```
    func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 460 {

            let data = // response from previous request's data object of type Data


            let delayTime = 2.0
            completion(request.retryCount < 3, delayTime)
        } else {
            completion(false, 0.0)
        }
    }
```

I tried to get the data object through the task but I always get nil :

```
let data = request.task?.originalRequest?.httpBody
```

Is there a way to get `DataResponse` object in the should function

Alternatively is there a way to call the Alamofire retrier manually

Comment: Alamofire SessionManager has `open var retrier: Alamofire.RequestRetrier?`, you can implement your class to manage your problem

Comment: im not sure I understand do you mind giving an example

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md look for Adapting and Retrying Requests

Comment: the retry and adapting works however when I make a request and it fails the backend returns info that I need in the next retry request . The data is inside the DataResponse object which alamofire requests return. Now my question is that , is there a way I can access this object in the ```  func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {}```